# Marcar Check y Cargar INPUT

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Estoy presentando la siguiente interface:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando le doy click me habilita un campo de texto para indicar una cantidad de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto se esta guardando en Base de datos, el INSERT lo hace correctamente, pero necesito realizar un update de estos campos por lo que primero deberia de cargarme los datos que ya tenia en la base de datos y mantenerme marcado el Ckeckbox

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando se le de click al boton de update que es el del circulo rojo me abre un modal en el cual es donde quiero que me muestre los checks marcados y con los datos registrados en la BD para que se vea asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para esto lo estoy tratando de hacer asi

```js
< script >
  function mod_comprobar_ano(obj) {
    if (obj.checked) {
      document.getElementById('mod_boton_ano').style.display = "";
    } else {
      document.getElementById('mod_boton_ano').style.display = "none";
    }
  }

function mod_comprobar_mes(obj) {
  if (obj.checked) {
    document.getElementById('mod_boton_mes').style.display = "";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('mod_boton_mes').style.display = "none";
  }
}

function mod_comprobar_dia(obj) {
  if (obj.checked) {
    document.getElementById('mod_boton_dia').style.display = "";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('mod_boton_dia').style.display = "none";
  }
}

function mod_comprobar_hora(obj) {
  if (obj.checked) {
    document.getElementById('mod_boton_hora').style.display = "";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('mod_boton_hora').style.display = "none";
  }
} <
/script>
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Duración Servicio <span class="required"> * </span></label>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
      <input name="mod_chec_ano" type="checkbox" id="mod_chec_ano" onChange="mod_comprobar_ano(this);" />
      <label for="mod_chec_ano">Años</label>
      <input type="number" name="mod_boton_ano" id="mod_boton_ano" style="display:none" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"></label>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
      <input name="mod_chec_mes" type="checkbox" id="mod_chec_mes" onChange="mod_comprobar_mes(this);" />
      <label for="mod_chec_mes">Meses</label>
      <input type="number" name="mod_boton_mes" id="mod_boton_mes" style="display:none" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"></label>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
      <input name="mod_chec_dia" type="checkbox" id="mod_chec_dia" onChange="mod_comprobar_dia(this);" />
      <label for="mod_chec_dia">Días</label>
      <input type="number" name="mod_boton_dia" id="mod_boton_dia" style="display:none" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"></label>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
      <input name="mod_chec_hora" type="checkbox" id="mod_chec_hora" onChange="mod_comprobar_hora(this);" />
      <label for="mod_chec_hora">Horas</label>
      <input type="number" name="mod_boton_hora" id="mod_boton_hora" style="display:none" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola Julián. ¿Por qué usas un modal? Puedes mostrar/ocultar contenido en la misma ventana de forma dinámica y es mucho mejor desde el punto de vista de la experiencia de usuario. Por otra parte, ¿cuál es el error o el problema?

Comment: El modal lo utilizo por que me carga todos la informacion registrada, este es solo un campo mas por decirlo de alguna manera de un monton de campos y todos se pueden editar para darle al usuario la posiblidad de corregir cualquier error y realmente no me da ningun error solo me carga todo en blanco, no marca los checks ni me carga la informacion de la caja de texto, gracias

Comment: No logro descifrar lo del modal y, parecería que quieres cargar de nuevo en el modal datos que ya tienes en la ventana actual ¿? ¿No es mejor habilitar un contenedor de la misma ventana para mostrar esos datos adicionales que traería el modal? No logro entender la lógica que estás siguiendo y me parece redundante si quieres cargar de nuevo los checkbox en el modal.

Comment: Habría que saber que atributos utilizas para guardar esos valores en tu tabla. Puede ser que que uses 4 attr (boolean) para los checks y 4 attr(int) para los valores. O sólo utilices 4 attr (int ALLOW NULL), si es null = unckeck sino check + valor